# electron Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

It is my first time using electron and I faced this error while creating a quit button.

I went thru like 50 threads and most of them said use require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()
and it did not work

electron version :20.1.1

should I downgrade electron to work?

or should I reinstall electron?

or maybe create a new project?

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getCurrentWindow')
    at document.getElementById.onclick (render.js:6:25)
```

my index.js file:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
require('@electron/remote/main').initialize(); 

if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) {
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    frame: false,
    enableRemoteModule: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      webPreferences: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    },
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

app.on('ready', createWindow);


app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }

});

app.on('activate', () => {
  
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

render.js

```js
const { remote } = require('@electron/remote')

document.getElementById('close').onclick = function() {
    console.log("debug")
    var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.close();
}
```

and html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Instapath</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <script defer src="render.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="content">
    <button id="close" style="position:fixed;">Close</button>
    <div><h1>Hi!</h1></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try using `const remote = require('electron').remote` or `const {remote} = require('electron')`

Comment: @ht006 Didn't work :{

Comment: is it the same error ?

Comment: Yes @ht006 it is

Comment: try to follow its migrating from remote section 


  [1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@electron/remote?activeTab=readme

Comment: remote is deprecated and removed from electron.js so you have to migrate ):